# Importing SVG as React component not working with Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, next.js

I created a project with create-react-app using Typescript and latter I was asked to add next.js to it, what happend was that it broked some svgs across the application. To fix that I added this package: `https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-images`

on my **next.config.js** I ended up with this **configuration**:

```
module.exports = withImages({
  webpack: config => {
    return config
  },
})
```

with this configuration I can now see my images across the application, but just the public ones, if I try to add a svg like a React component following this approach:

```
import { ReactComponent as IconPlus } from 'assets/icons/icon-plus.svg'
```

I end up with this error:

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in
> components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got:
> undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file
> it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

I tried to add **react-svg-inline** as I saw in some other posts, so I ended up adding .babelrc for Next.js like this:

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "inline-react-svg"
  ]
}
```

After changing this I changed my svg import to just:

```
import IconPlus from 'assets/icons/icon-plus.svg'
```

and used it like

after adding .babelrc and the inline-react-svg, I get this error:

> Syntax error: Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't
> currently enabled (5:10):

Any help on this, Am I doing something wrong on the babel configuration, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Change `.babelrc` to be:

```json
{
  "presets": ["next/babel"],
  "plugins": ["inline-react-svg"]
}
```

Import your `.svg` files relative to their location:

```
import IconPlus from "../assets/icons/icon-plus.svg";
```

You can read more about import absolute paths [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/module-path-aliases).

If you just want to create React components from `.svg`, you don't have to use `next-images`.

Here is a working example https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/svg-components.

Answer (score -1):

you dont need to add any library, if you want, you can create a new component with that svg you have. Imagine you have your source folder organized like that:

-component

|--SvgIconPlus

|---index.tsx

-page

|-index.tsx

1- Just copy the svg file inside the return component

```
export default function SvgIconPlusComponent() {
    return (
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 12.27 12" xmlns:v="https://vecta.io/nano"><path d="M11.17 4.38L6.88 8.99V0h-1.5v8.99L1.1 4.38 0 5.4 6.13 12l6.14-6.6-1.1-1.02z" fill="#000"/></svg>
    );
}
```

2- Import it in your page index.tsx

```
import SvgIconPlusComponent from '../components/SvgIconPlus'
export default function MyPage(){
    return(<div><SvgIconPlusComponent /></div>);
}
```

Comment: This requires altering the SVG files and essentially adopting an entirely new organizational framework for organizing SVG assets. +1 for clever thinking but minus several for portability.

Comment: there is no change in the svg file properly

Comment: Show me how this works for `logo.svg` in a way that I don't have to change that file.

Comment: if you open your svg file as a text, you can see that my example has one, copy that text opened and create the component as I created

Comment: Oh, I see the confusion. I mean not altering the *SVG file that's being loaded*. Creating a separate component file, manually, isn't scalable for most of the web projects I work with. SVGR-type solutions that, I'm sure are doing something similar under the hood, that doesn't require altering original SVG files is the only reasonable path forward IMO. CRA did it well enough, Vite has great support, as does Next. No reason I can see to do it this way.

Comment: ok, but my option work, and without installing any other lib

Comment: I'm not saying it doesn't *work* I'm saying it's *bad practice* because it necessitates maintaining a separate file for every `*.svg` file you intend to load this way. If you have a small project it might not be a big deal. If you have a larger project with lots of devs touching lots of files suddenly things it's going to become a burden, fast.

Comment: it depends on how you organize it. All svg icons can be separete in one component/svgicons folder. What is the difference from public/img/svicons from that?